# Does the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}$ exist?

Tags: limits

For $x$ given, what do you think about the following limit?

> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}.
> $$

What I tried and what are the problems that I am facing:

Let $f(x, n)=\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}$. We have:

$$
\log f(x, n)=\dfrac{1}{n}\log\left(x^n-1\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\log\left(1-x^{-n}\right)+\dfrac{1}{n}\log\left(x^n\right),
$$

first, I do not know if I can apply the log or not? I guess $x$ must be real? and must be positive? what about complex?

Finally, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}=\log x.
$$

Comment: I would imagine that this problem only makes sense when $x$ is a positive real number, because the $n$th root is not well-defined if $x^n-1$ is not positive.

Comment: Also, what you have proved is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log f(x,n) = \log(x)$, not $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x,n) = \log(x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a down and dirty solution, for large $n$, (and assuming $x>1$, since otherwise how can you take $n$ th root),

$$\frac{1}{2}x^n \leq x^n-1 \leq x^n$$
so

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}x \leq (x^n-1)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq x$$
So 
$$(x^n-1)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
\to x$$

Comment: Excellent answer! It should be noted that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a}=1$, so we are using the squeeze theorem here.

Comment: To editors well obviously $a$ must be positive, I thought I was pathetic spending all my time aswering these questions, but I guess you are doing me one better.

Comment: I spend time answering the questions I can, there are so many technical questions on the site that are way above my head.

Comment: @AlexSchiff  yes, I changed my answer a little, your remark made me think that you can just use a fixed $a$, in the limit you give.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Well sorry if I was harsh, it just seems to me that editing other people questions and answers is a waste of time, if they write something I dont like, or is wrong, I just make a comment, I think it is polite.

Comment: Sorry Rene, didn't mean to offend. I thought it was a small change so I didn't think it would be a big deal.

Comment: No its Ok I am not mad at you.

Comment: This is a really nice solution. simple and clear. +1

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if I may, just for fun:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}=e^{ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n})}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ln\left(x^n-1\right)^{1/n}}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(x^nln(x)\right)}{x^n-1}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(x^n(ln(x))^2\right)}{x^n(lnx)}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}lnx}=e^{lnx}=x$

Comment: That is the approach OP gave, in disguise

Comment: I know... still won't hurt and might help others